# почему после ввода новых данных сразу закрывает программу

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
what = input(' ')
def func():
    if what == 0:
        return what
func()
```

как сделать что бы когда вводился 0 возвращала what
 и при вводе новых данных не закрывало программу 
 а вызывало другую написанную функцию

Comment: `input` всегда возвращает строку, поэтому условие `what == 0` никогда не выполняется. Когда вводите 0, то в `what` попадает строка `'0'`, с ней и нужно сравнивать.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func():
    what = int(input())
    if what == 0:
        print(what)
        func()
    else:
        func()
```

выйти из программы можно комбинацией <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите рекурсивно вызывать ф-цию, можно внести фрагмент с вводом внутрь неё. И если у вас ввод `input()` то вы принимаете строку, и сравнивать ее нужно не с числом `0` а со строковым значением `'0'`

```
def func():
    what = input()
    if what == '0':  #Сравниваем со строкой, а не с числом
        return what
    return func()    #Если условие не выполнено - вызываем ф-цию снова


print(func())
```